# Subset list of dataframes by column name

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a list of dataframes `df_list=[df1,df2,df3]` and a list of column headers I am interested in. `col_list=['Fire','Water','Wind','Hail']`

I want to loop through each dataframe df_list, and create a new dataframe with only the columns in col_list.The issue is if one of the elements in col_list is not in the df I still want it to make the dataframe however simply without that column.

What I tried doing is,

```
for data_frame in df_list:
   try:
       data_frame=data_frame[['Fire','Water','Wind','Hail']]
   except:
        continue
```

However, this does not give the result I am looking for.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. Could you add a list of a couple minimal input data frames and an example of the output you would like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a list comprehension:

```
[data_frame[['Fire','Water','Wind','Hail']] for data_frame in df_list]
```

If some data_frames do not have all the columns you can use [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) instead:

```
[data_frame.reindex(columns=['Fire','Water','Wind','Hail']) for data_frame in df_list]
```

---

Inside the for loop:

```
data_frame=data_frame[['Fire','Water','Wind','Hail']]
```

is overwriting the data_frame variable BUT not updating the i-th item of df_list.
This is equivalent to the following code:

```
In [11]: a = [1, 2, 3]

In [12]: for i in a:
    ...:     i = i + 1
    ...:

In [13]: a
Out[13]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: In which way is this solving OPs problem with varying columns? Additionally, I don't see why a list comprehension helps with the problem.

Comment: @Markus since you're going to use pd.concat on the resulting list. My assumption is this is what the rest of OP's code goes on to do.

Comment: @Markus "I want to loop through each dataframe df_list, and create a new dataframe with only the columns in col_list."

Comment: Hmm but Bjc51192 states that some dataframes do not contain all columns listed in col_list, which (as I understood) raises errors for him.

Comment: @Markus you make a good point, thanks! You should use reindex in these cases.

Comment: Andy, this worked perfect. One question, when I reindex what happens to the dfs that do not contain a specific column? Would it get a 1 in its place?

Comment: @Bjc51192 it gets NaN, you could fillna(1) if that wasn't sufficient :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehensions to get the subset of cols that are in `col_list`. However, when you're iterating, the `data_frame` var only has a reference to the object, changing it won't actually change the element in the array. You could keep another list with the "sub dataframes".

```
sub_df_list = []
for data_frame in df_list:
    sub_df_list.append(
        data_frame[[col for col in data_frame.columns if col in col_list]]
    )
```

Edit:

As pointed out in another answer, you could do this as a single list comprehension... which is a bit hard on the eyes:

```
sub_df_list = [
    data_frame[[col for col in data_frame.columns if col in col_list]]
    for data_frame in df_list
]
```

Edit 2:

Pandas columns are an `Index` object. These have set operations, such as `intersection`. The easiest way to do what you're after is:

```
sub_df_list = [
    data_frame[data_frame.columns.intersection(col_list)] for data_frame in df_list
]
```

Comment: Your second edit is in my opinion the best (and most readable) solution.